# Div usage in tables in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to write some HTML/CSS to display a certain row with some of the elements left-aligned and some of them in the center. This was my HTML code:

```
<tr class="mainInfo" id="header"> 
    <td> Item </td>
    <td> Color </td>
    <td> Size </td>
    <div class="mid">
        <td> Subtotal </td>
        <td> Tax </td>
        <td> Total </td>
    </div>
</tr>
```

And this is my CSS code:

```
.mid { 
    text-align: center; 
} 
.mainInfo { 
    font: bold 13px Tahoma;   
} 
#header { 
    background-color: #68891; 
    color: white; 
}
```

But the last three elements are not moving to the center, and I really don't understand why not. I tried putting `class="mid"` in the `<td>` tags and that worked, but doesn't that defeat the purpose of DRY?

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: HTML isn't so great with DRY. You could use n-th child, but you're allowed to just put the class on every <td> in this case. http://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/

Comment: A `td` has to be the child of a `tr`.

Comment: If those 3 table cells require to be centered, then you can either give the elements the class in html or target the three childs of the table row in css or javascript. To be honest I think it would be easier to just add the class in html.

Comment: Your HTML is not compliant with the norm. Refrain from having `DIV` inside `TR`. Only `TD` should be inside `TR`, not `DIV`.

Comment: @vijitha I added an example to my answer. Maybe this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Yup, that worked. Thank you! Also thanks for mentioning the validator, I didn't know about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot put a `div` instead of `td` element.
You should validate your HTML code with [w3 validator](http://validator.w3.org/).
If you'll do so you'll see you get this error message:

> document type does not allow element "DIV" here; missing one of "TH", "TD" start-tag

Maybe you can do it this way:

```
<table>
    <tr class="mainInfo" id="header"> 
        <td> Item </td>
        <td> Color </td>
        <td> Size </td>
        <td class="center">Subtotal</td>
        <td class="center">Tax</td>
        <td class="center">Total</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/2DB32/1/)**

Answer (score 3):

No, you should not put divs inside tr's or tables.

And you should not use tr's or td's without table-element.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>hello world</td>
    <!-- This is bare minimum to use tables properly -->
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can insert whatever(not tr or td, but could start new table) you want inside TD-elements though.

It's possible to use other elements to replace these standard ones with css display-property set to table-row etc., but you should stick to conventional tags.

Use colspan/rowspan to span over multiple table columns or rows.

Comment: So then would I put <td class="mid> for each one? Thanks for the response!

Comment: Could you clarify how you wanted this to render with a drawing of some sort? I'm unsure what the original div's function in your markup is. Is it a new row?

Comment: No, it was just meant to align the words Subtotal, Tax, and Total to the center of each of their cells.

Comment: Yes, you could give the td's a class with css-style text-align: center; or as inline style

Answer (score 1):

CSS classes are designed to be used as often you need/want to. Only IDs should appear once per page. 
Of course you should always keep the DRY concept in mind but in your case it's totally fine. It wouldn't if you would set your `.mid` class to every `<td>` because in that case you could just set the properties directly to the `<td>` element.

Answer (score 1):

`middle` is not a valid value for `text-align`, so I'm going to assume, in your CSS, that's meant to be `vertical-align`. If so, it's because `vertical-align` will only apply to table cells, not `div`s - that would explain why it is only being successfully applied to your `td`s.

Additionally, you shouldn't really put a `div` inside a table (and shouldn't put a `td` inside of that) but that's not related to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assign one class for left alignment and other for center like so...

```
.left {
   text-align:left;
}

.center {
   text-align:center;
}
```

Asign class to TD elements

```
<tr class="mainInfo" id="header"> 
   <td class='left'> Item </td>
   <td class='center'> Color </td>    
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! Why would this change the result? The left-justified elements are fine, only the center ones are having trouble...